# Is it possible to get data payload when app is in background without clicking on notification in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't get data payload when app is in background.
Unable to put custom notification on Status Bar. Please Help?

Comment: are you using firebase console, or sending push messages yourself?

Comment: No I'm not using firebase console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Firebase console then no. If you send a message from the Firebase console and your app is in the background then any custom data will only be available through the notification. If the user never taps on the notification that accompanying data is lost.

If you want to send data to your application that is critical to its operation then you should send data messages, which you can do via the FCM REST API.

See more on the different types of messages in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

Comment: Thanks Bro. Saved time.